# Перезагрузка скриптов

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли на JS динамически перезагрузить подключенные скрипты (обновить их кэш - загрузить `script.js?time=111` с текущим значением времени)?

```
<button>Перезагрузить</button>
<script>
$(documet).on('click', 'button', function() {
   console.info('script.js обновлен');
});
</script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы можете удалить скрипты, а потом заново их вставить. Простое изменение `src` не поможет.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вы уверены, что скрипт можно вот так взять и удалить?

Comment: @PavelMayorov удалить можно. Повлияет ли это на созданные в нем глобальные переменные - нет. Но при повторной загрузке они переопределяться. Хотя да, признаю, решение может содержать баги.

Comment: Сильно зависит от того, что эти скрипты делают. В общем случае нельзя.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko переменные-то переопределятся - а вот повешенные обработчики событий повешаются повторно, со всеми последствиями.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, вы правы, решение не подходящее.